# Calculus, water poured into a cone: Why is the derivative non-linear?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If water is poured into a cone at a constant rate and if $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is the rate of change of the depth of the water, I understand that $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is decreasing. However, I don't understand why $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is non-linear. Why can't it be linear?

I am NOT asking whether or not the height function is linear. Many are telling me that the derivative of height is not a constant so thus the height function is not linear, but this is not what I am asking.

This is my mistake, because I had used $h(t)$ originally to denote the derivative of height which is what my book used. **Rather I am asking if $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is linear or not and why.** It would be nice if someone could better explain what my book is telling me:

> At every instant the portion of the cone containing water is similar to the entire cone; the volume is proportional to the cube of the depth of the water. The rate of change of depth (the derivative) is therefore not linear.

Comment: The higher the depth of water in the cone, the more “room” it has to spread out.  Layers of water near the top will be much thinner than layers of water of equal volume near the bottom.

Comment: One way to understand it visually is with martini glasses. They're only half full (in volume) when they look almost full (79% of the height). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ut_0LvLQmI4

Comment: What an unexpectedly great question.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> I understand that $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is decreasing. However, I don't understand on an **intuitive** level why $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is non-linear.

Because any strictly decreasing function that is linear eventually becomes negative, but you already know that $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is always positive.

Comment: Wait but if the derivative of height is not linear but is always decreasing it will also eventually become negative.

Comment: Oh there must be an asymptote right?

Comment: yes i did say intuitive before my bad. This answer is just one sentence and my question has been answered :)

Comment: @user532874: That's in fact correct. A strictly decreasing positive real function must have an asymptote. This is a consequence of the fact that any non-empty subset of reals that has a lower bound has a limit, which you will encounter and prove in a real analysis course.

Comment: @user532874: Sorry I accidentally wrote wrongly in my above comment; any non-empty subset of reals that has a lower bound has an infimum (greatest lower bound), and hence any decreasing positive function must have a limit.

Comment: But $h$ can only be positive, so talking about what a linear function has to do over the real line isn't really relevant.

Comment: @Acccumulation: You seem to have missed the question; it's not about $h$ but about $\frac{dh}{dt}$, and my answer answers the quoted question...

Comment: You said "Because any strictly decreasing function that is linear eventually becomes negative" But that is true only if we look at it over the whole real line. Your statement is false in this context, because $h$ is constrained to be positive, and hence there is some region of time that is excluded from consideration.

Comment: @Acccumulation: No, that statement is true when you look only on the positive half line. The full meaning of the statement "the function eventually becomes negative" is "there exists a constant $K \in \mathbb R$ such that the function is negative on the half-line $(K,+\infty)$", and if this is true then the following stronger statement is also true: "there exists a POSITIVE constant $K > 0$ such that the function is negative on the half line $(K,+\infty)$".

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yup, thanks for replying for me. =)

Answer (score 17):

The volume of water is changing linearly, but the height and volume are related nonlinearly. That is why $h(t)$ is non-linear.

\begin{eqnarray*}
V &=& \frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h\\
r &=& h \tan \theta\\
V &=& \frac{1}{3} \pi \tan^2 \theta h^3\\
\frac{dV}{dt} &=& \frac{1}{3} \pi \tan^2 \theta 3 h^2 \frac{dh}{dt}\\
\end{eqnarray*}

$\frac{dV}{dt}$ is a constant because the constant filling rate. So you can see from the above equation that $\frac{dh}{dt}$ is not constant.

Comment: +1, but if you could finish the calculation of $\frac{dh}{dt}$ as an explicit function of $t$ then this answer would be even better :)

Comment: No, he means "not constant" in that dh/dt is a function that changes with time. Treat dV/dt and dh/dt as variables and solve for dh/dt...

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer my question I should have used clearer notation

Comment: It may be helpful to note that the proportion dV/dh is exactly equal to the area of the top surface of the water, and when we're talking about a cone, that area is proportional to h^2 (so not linear, or inverse linear).

Answer (score 6):

The top radius $r$ of the cone is proportional to $h$: We have $r(t)=c\>h(t)$ for some constant $c$. Therefore $V(t)=c\> h^3(t)$ with some other $c$, or $h(t)=c\> V^{1/3}(t)$.  This implies $${dh\over dt}=c\> V^{-2/3}(t) V'(t)=c\> V^{-2/3}(t)\ ,$$ since $V'(t)$ is constant. Now $t\mapsto V(t)$ is linear; hence $t\mapsto V^{-2/3}(t)$ is a "root function", and not linear.

Comment: It might be a bit confusing that the $c$ in $cV^{-2/3}(t)$ is $cV'(t)$ in the expression $cV^{-2/3}V'(t)$.

Comment: best response yet. I understand everything except for how do I know the radius is proportional to the height? In order for radius to be proportional to height, wouldn't volume have to stay constant?

Comment: @user532874 $r = h \tan \theta$, and $\theta$ is constant, so the radius is proportional to height.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine slicing the cone into circular cross-sections.  These cross-sections get bigger as you go up the cone.  Let's think about two cross-sections in particular:  one slice spanning between 1 cm and 1.01 cm from the bottom, and another slice spanning between 5 cm and 5.01 cm from the bottom.  Since the higher "slice" has a larger volume, and the water is entering the cone at a constant rate of volume per time, it must have taken longer for the water to rise from 5 cm to 5.01 cm than it took for the water to rise from 1 cm to 1.01 cm.  Thus, $dh/dt$ (the rate at which the water is rising) is decreasing as $h$ increases.

Comment: Almost there - you've shown that dh/dt is decreasing as h increases, but not that it's a nonlinear relationship. The accepted answer nails this in an intuitive way - the water level in the cone is always rising, so dh/dt  > 0 for all h. If dh/dt was a linearly decreasing function, it would become negative at some point, so that cannot be the case. Therefore, dh/dt is a nonlinear decreasing function.

Comment: Ah, yes, upon re-reading the question I realize that I was answering the question "why is $h$ not a linear function of $t$?" rather than "why is $dh/dt$ not a linear function of $t$?"

Answer (score 1):

You can write the volume of the cone as 
$V = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\pi\cdot \left(h\tan\theta\right)^2\cdot h $.
Here, we are writing $r =h\cdot\tan(\theta)$.

Coming to your question, the radius increases with an exponent of 2 and on the whole volume increases with the height cubed. So by intuition you can say that height must be varying with $t^{1/3}$ so as to balance things out since the rate of water being filled is constant.

You can also work it out as $h(t) = At^{1/3} + C$ 
; $A = (3k/\pi)^{1/3}$, $k = $ rate of change of vol. and $C$ is arbitrary constant .

Comment: You should read the [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have interpreted my question correctly but I can't understand why height varies with t^1/3 and how this proves the derivative is nonlinear.

Answer (score 1):

The notion by Mike is nearly correct. Christian points out the correct result without being overly specific.

If you consider the volume of a cone of maximum height $h$ and maximum radius $R$ but only calculate it to the height $h'<h$, you can shuffle the equation to give that height depending on the volume of that fraction of the cone:
$$h'=\left(\frac{3V h²}{\pi R²}\right)^{1/3}$$ 
We assume the tip of the cone pointing downwards and the opening in positive $z$-direction with the water pouring in from above that, so no sideway filling.

If you than put in $\frac{dV}{dt}\cdot t$ as the volume depending on the time, where $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is the constant that describes how much water is added to the cone per time element, you get:
$$\frac{dh'}{dt}\sim t^{-2/3}$$

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically speaking, for a cone you have $$V=\frac {\pi}{ 3}  r^2 h$$

$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \frac {\pi}{3}  [ 2rh \frac{dr}{dt} +r^2 \frac{dh}{dt}]$$

Since $$\frac {dr}{dt}=c\frac {dh}{dt}$$ we get

$$\frac {dV}{dt} = \frac {\pi}{3}  [( c +r^2) \frac{dh}{dt}]$$

While $\frac {dV}{dt}$ is constant,  $\frac {dh}{dt}$ depends on $r$ and does not seem  to be linear.

Comment: Sorry this doesn't answer my question I should have used clearer notation

Answer (score 0):

Phrasing it $\frac {dh}{dt}$ is a bit wrong, as the $h$ is not a direct function of $t$. You may be considering a situation where water is being poured into the cone at constant rate, in which case volume is proportional to time. But then $t$ is just a proxy for $V$, and it would be more instructive to deal with $\frac {dh}{dV}$. That in turn is the reciprocal of $\frac {dV}{dh}$. And if we take an infinitesimal slice of the cone, that slice will be a frustrum. However, the surface area of the top of that frustrum will be almost the same as the surface area of the bottom (since it's an infinitesimal slice), and so we can approximate it with a cylinder. The volume of the cylinder is the surface area of the base time the height: $V=Ah$, so $\frac V h = A$. It therefore follows that $\frac {dV}{dh}$ at a particular height is the cross sectional area at that height.

As an intuitive explanation of this, suppose $m$ is the height of one molecule of water (strictly speaking, how much height a molecule takes up isn't well defined, but since this is just an intuitive explanation, I'll put that aside). To make the height of water go up $m$, you have to put in one layer of water molecules, and the amount of water that you need is going to be proportional to the surface area.

Thus,  $\frac {dh}{dV}$ is the reciprocal of the area, so for it to be linear, the area would have to be the reciprocal of a linear function. Besides the fact that there is no reason to suppose that the area is such a function, we can directly see that it isn't by calculating it; it is proportional to height squared. We can also see that the area is zero at the base of the cone, so $\frac {dh}{dV}$ is infinity there, so it's not linear.